# Getting weird value in Double

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point

Hello i made a "Clicker" as a first project while learning swift i have an automated timer that is supposed to remove some numbers from other numbers but sometimes i get values like 0.600000000000001 and i have no idea why.

Here is my "Attack" function that removes 0.2 from the Health of a zombie.

```
let fGruppenAttackTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("fGruppenAttackTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func fGruppenAttackTime() {
    zHealth -= 0.2 
    if zHealth <= 0 {
        zHealth = zSize
        pPengar += pPengarut
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is my `attackZ` button that is supposed to remove 1 from the health of the zombie

```
@IBAction func attackZ(sender: UIButton) {
    zHealth -= Double(pAttack)
    fHunger -= 0.05
    fGruppenHunger.progress = Float(fHunger / 100)
    Actionlbl.text = ""
    if zHealth <= 0 {
        zHealth = zSize
        pPengar += pPengarut
    }
}
```

Lastly here are the variables value:

```
var zHealth = 10.0
var zSize = 10.0
var pAttack = 1
var pPengar = 0
var pPengarut = 1
```

When the timer is on and the function is running and i click the button i sometimes get weird values like 0.600000000000001 and if i set the 0.2 in the function to 0.25 i get 0.0999999999999996 sometimes. I wonder why this happens and what to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [trojanfoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747237/1271826), he [shares a link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) that describes the source of the problem regarding rounding of floating point numbers.

In terms of what to do, there are a number of approaches:

1. You can shift to integer types. For example, if your existing values can all be represented with a maximum of two decimal places, multiply those by 100 and then use `Int` types everywhere, excising the `Double` and `Float` representations from your code.
2. You can simply deal with the very small variations that `Double` type introduces. For example:

   - If displaying the results in the UI, use `NumberFormatter` to convert the `Double` value to a `String` using a specified number of decimal places.

     ```
     let formatter = NumberFormatter()
     formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
     formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0  // or you might use `2` here, too
     formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

     print(formatter.string(for: value)!)
     ```

     By the way, the `NSNumberFormatter` enjoys another benefit, too, namely that it honors the localization settings for the user. For example, if the user lives in Germany, where the decimal place is represented with a `,` rather than a `.`, the `NSNumberFormatter` will use the user's native number formatting.
   - When testing to see if a number is equal to some value, rather than just using `==` operator, look at the difference between two values and seeing if they're within some permissible rounding threshold.
3. You can use `Decimal`/`NSDecimalNumber`, which doesn't suffer from rounding issues when dealing with decimals:

   ```
   var value = Decimal(string: "1.0")!
   value -= Decimal(string: "0.9")!
   value -= Decimal(string: "0.1")!
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   var value = Decimal(1)
   value -= Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -1, significand: 9)
   value -= Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -1, significand: 1)
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   var value = Decimal(1)
   value -= Decimal(9) / Decimal(10)
   value -= Decimal(1) / Decimal(10)
   ```

   Note, I explicitly avoid using any `Double` values such as `Decimal(0.1)` because creating a `Decimal` from a fractional `Double` only captures whatever imprecision `Double` entails, where as the three examples above avoid that entirely.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has no double currently (it features a "decimal" or "value")

Comment: Yeah, and we shouldn't even be using `NSDecimalNumber` anymore, anyways. We use `Decimal`. I've also updated the `NumberFormatter` example for Swift 3 and later, too.

Comment: I must confess I used today NSDecimalNumber and it gave the same weird issue. I must try Decimal now  :-)

Comment: When I stumbled upon this question, I was trying an apparently simple thing: everytime a button was clicked, I subtracted 0.01 from a Double (a member of a class). Anything went just fine BUT when in the end there's a situation where code has to subtract 0.01 - 0.01 I get -3.46944695195361e-18   :-)

Comment: If a function is expected to receive a Double argument what's the safest way to convert Decimal to Double?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164886/discussion-between-rob-and-3000).

Answer (score 5):

It's because of floating point rounding errors.

For further reading, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.