# Is anyone facing this kind of issue in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

In Chrome developer tools, manipulating values like code below:

```
var total=0;
total+=32;
total+=11.2;
total+=3.2;
```

the result I am getting is:

```
46.400000000000006
```

i am confused, why is the 6 added at the end?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting weird value in Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747174/getting-weird-value-in-double)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet the canonical dupe has over 2,000 linked questions, that seems more than enough signposts. And generally: people's votes are their own, don't tell them what to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Generally, people's votes are their own", can agree with this, but also agree with the general feeling on the blog/meta that stack isn't welcoming for newer users, just downvoting because he didn't find the info by himself contribute to that